# Collective nouns

Tags: sentence-construction

We could say the "the family is or are" it depends if we think about it as the whole or rather about individul people. I know that a/on only go with singular words therfore I wouldn't say "a team are" right I need to put nothing or the before team to use are. Is that right?

Comment: Whether you use a singular or plural verb has nothing to do with whether you use the definite or indefinite article.

Comment: You're British. Thus, you know that we coud say "The team is checking for information" or "The team are checking for informstion". First examplr treats "team" as a unit and seconf as many individual people some look for information some don't. My question  when I say "A team" instead of " the team" can I still say "A team are looking for informstion" or not?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: using are/is has zero to do with a/the.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. **Team** is singular, but it refers to a group of people. The plural of **team** is **teams** -- more than one distinct group of people. For example:

> This team is the best.
> The teams are playing tonight.

**Team** is a countable noun, so it follows the same rules as other countable nouns for using articles. When it's singular, you use the definite or indefinite article:

> The team is getting on the bus.
> A team is a group of people who cooperate with each other to win.

When it's plural, you use the definite article to refer to a specific group and no article to refer to them in general:

> The teams will compete until there is only one team left.
> Teams are expected to clean up after themselves.

You don't use an article when referring to specific teams by name when "team" is a part of the name. For example:

> Team A plays Team B tonight at 8:00.
> Team C has been disqualified.

Comment: "A team are", e.g. "A team are playing here tonight", sounds OK to me - maybe because I'm British.

Comment: Probably. I don't think an American would ever say that.